# Integration flow with PollableChannel in Spring Cloud Stream application causes scheduled tasks to be not triggered anymore

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

We're having a Spring Cloud Stream application with some scheduled tasks and added a new producer by adding a `Supplier` bean. The `Supplier` gets its input from a `PollableChannel`.

Since we've introduced the `PollableChannel`, the scheduled tasks are not fired by its cron expression anymore, as long no messages are present in the `PollableChannel`.

Its a Spring Boot 3.0.5 application with Spring Cloud Stream 2022.0.1.

I've provided a demo application on Github: https://github.com/sbillmaier/supplierAndTaskScheduler.git

As long the `MessageSource`configured in `EventFlowConfig` returns `null`, the scheduled task `ScheduledTask.doScheduled()` is not fired anymore.

I've expected that the scheduled task is fired based on its cron even if there are no messages in the `PollableChannel`.

The current workaround is to define a custom `TaskScheduler` in `SchedulingConfig`.

What are the inner workings in Spring Boot/Spring Integration/Spring Cloud Stream causing this?
Is this a possible bug, that the autoconfigured `TaskScheduler` is somehow "disabled"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is correct. The auto-configured `TaskScheduler` comes with a single thread in its pool: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.task-execution-and-scheduling.

So, to mitigate the problem with your current versions, you need to increase that `spring.task.scheduling.pool.size` configuration property value. I believe it is exactly what you do with your custom `TaskScheduler`.

In the latest Spring Integration version we did some further mitigation to not block on those queues indefinitely: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-6.0-to-6.1-Migration-Guide